# how can jquery remove row dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-select2, jquery-selectbox

I am using jquery1.9 , I want to add or remove a line dynamicly by click the `add/remove image`

The below is the most important html code:

```
<ul id="topic_courses_list">
  <li class="section_form_li1">
      <div class="section_form_div1">
          <select id="topic_courses" class="chzn-select" data-placeholder="Please chose a course" style="width:350px;" tabindex="1">
          </select>
      </div>
      <div class="section_form_div1">
          <img id="topic_add_course_img" src="../../imgs/btn_30x22_add.gif"/>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

When I click the `add` image whose id is `topic_add_course_img`, add a new line and this line have a `delete image`, which I can remove the new line by click it.

Here's my code

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#topic_add_course_img', function(){
        var course_name = $("#topic_courses").find("option:selected").text();
        var course_val = $('#topic_courses').val();

        var chtml = '<li class="section_form_li1">' +
         '   <div class="section_form_div1">'+course_name+'&nbsp;' +
         '       <img src="../../imgs/btn_30x22_delete.gif" align="absmiddle" />' +
         '   </div>' +
         '</li>'
         $("#topic_courses_list").append(chtml);

 });
```

Yeah, I got the results what I want, but I cannot delete a row by click the image.
Because even I give the line a dynamic id, I don't know which id is when I click the image?

Any answer is welcom :), Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a class to your image and use:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.yourClass', function(){

         $(this).remove();

 });
```

If you want to get rid of the parent:

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

Comment: glad it worked, if you find it helpful consider upvoting and accepting the answer so it remains useful for other users :)